# Same postgres script to use different users on different machines?

Tags: sql, postgresql, environment-variables, environment

The project I'm working on uses an sql script which runs a few commands as postgres's admin user; commands such as:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE azara WITH OWNER azara'
```

My colleagues are on osx and their admin postgres user is by default 'postgres', whereas I am on nixos and my admin postgres user is by default 'root'. So this command in the script would need to be different to run on my machine, being instead

```
psql -U root -c 'CREATE DATABASE azara WITH OWNER azara'
```

What is the best way to handle this difference?

Perhaps the easiest way would be to create a 'postgres' user on my machine to run the script. But that seems like kind of a hack, and I'm wondering if there is instead a way that I can set the script to determine which user to use.

I considered using a postgres [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-envars.html) that the script could use as a variable. But the command

```
$ echo $PGUSER
```

returns nothing and the environment variable PGUSER does not appear to be set by default, so it appears that my colleagues would have to set the envirenment variable for that to work.

**Is there a solution in which the script can use my default admin user, and which does not involve requiring my colleagues to alter their setups or how they run the script?**

Comment: Just create a bash script that receives the user as parameter then you would call `./myscript root` or `./myscript postgres`

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment's suggestion, I set my script to take an input parameter representing the intended username. The create database section now looks like

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then
  psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE azara WITH OWNER azara'
else
  psql -U $1 -c 'CREATE DATABASE azara WITH OWNER azara'
fi
```

This uses 'postgres' as the default user name in case no argument is provided, and uses the specified argument's value as the username if one is provided. That way how my colleagues run the script will not need to change as their username is the default, and I can use it by specifying my different username 'root' as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```sh
superuser=`psql -Atq -c 'SELECT usename FROM pg_catalog.pg_user WHERE usesysid = 10'`
psql -Atq -U "$superuser" -c 'CREATE DATABASE azara WITH OWNER azara'
```